# asyncio function not defined python 3.6

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.6

Ive been having trouble with this for a little while now. When declaring a async function like:

```
async def init(loop):
```

and then I call the function it returns a:

```
NameError: name 'init' is not defined
```

Here is how the code all looks:

```
class Server:

    def __init__(self, port):
        asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        server = loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))

        print("Serving on {}".format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
        try:
            loop.run_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\rclosing the server")
            pass

        server.close()
        loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
        loop.close()

    async def init(loop):
        server = await loop.create_server(handle_request, '127.0.0.1', 8881)
        return server

    async def handle_request():
```

Any direction that you could point me in would be helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `def init()` is inside your class.  Move it out of the class by unindenting it:

```
class Server:

    def __init__(self, port):
        #....
        loop.close()

    # IT SHOULD NOT BE HERE
#IT SHOULD BE HERE!!! 
async def init(loop):
    server = await loop.create_server(handle_request, '127.0.0.1', 8881)
    return server
```

Comment: `handle_request` will probably have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks. That did fix the problem!